# How do I display my HTML/CSS files on a browser via Visual Studio Code on Mac?

Tags: html, css, macos, browser, visual-studio-code

I HAVE looked around to find the solution and some fellows already expressed the command:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "Chrome",
    "osx": {
        "command": "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
    },
    "args": [
        "${file}"    
    ] 
}
```

after you press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and entering `Configure Task Runner`

This thing is, I don't see that option, thus preventing me from completing this step. Perhaps I am ignorant as to how to work in this still.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifiying a `"taskName":` attribute in your build task. *i.e.*

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "taskName": "MyName",
    "command": "Chrome",
    "osx": {
        "command": "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
    },
    "args": [
        "${file}"    
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=peakchen90.open-html-in-browser. It is written in an asian language but it is very simple to handle, when your html file is opened, save it, right click and click the asian words. It will open in your default browser.

[image]